# LimeSurvey Remote Control API: get responses that are irrelevant marked with "N/A"

Tags: rpc, limesurvey

I would like to get responses that are irrelevant (not displayed for the participant) marked as "N/A" when using Remote Control API, export_responses or export_responses_by_token methods.

When I use that methods and export "long" answers, only multiple choice, multiple choice with comments, and yes or no question types get responses with "N/A" when the question is irrelevant. I'm wondering why this occurs. Why LS only returns "N/A" in that types of questions and not for all the other types? At least if the question types are saved as CHAR in the data base.

When I export a VV file for the responses the questions that are irrelevant are displayed with "{question_not_shown}" in the responses cells of the csv exported, so I can't understand why normal csv export does not display "N/A" for all that are irrelevant.

I found a plugin ([Export complete answers (code and full answer) for LimeSurvey export](https://extensions.sondages.pro/export-statistics-and-database/exportcompleteanswers)) that do this when exporting from the LS interface, but I need to get the responses from my application, that uses Remote Control API.

I'm using version 2.73.1 for compatibility with my application. This behaviour changed in more recent versions of LS?

Is there a workaround in 2.73.1 version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can install exportCompleteAnswers and use it as format.
Format are `csv-allanswer` at https://api.limesurvey.org/classes/remotecontrol_handle.html#method_export_statistics

PS : i REALLY hate the N/A not updatable system (without any option) …

Comment: Thank you very much Denis. I noted that the responses for question type "Yes/No", when response is "No", is exported as "No", instead of "N" when the export is of type "by code". Another issue is that for question types "datetime", "multiple numerical input" and "numerical input", the responses are exported as "N/A" even when the question is relevant. I suppose that is because the plugin converts "NULL" from the database, to "N/A", right?

Comment: >  instead of "N" when the export is of type "by code".

LimeSurvey version ? Via GUI too ? Please : open a bug issue in the  respective git repo

> the responses are exported as "N/A" even when the question is relevant. I suppose that is because the plugin converts "NULL" from the database, to "N/A", right?

Yes : no way to know if date or numeric are shown or not.

Answer (score 0):

By the way you tell it looks like a bug: For text questions, the N/A is not shown for irrelevant.

Would you please paste the contents of the record you are evaluating?
Irrelevant questions should contain a null on their value.

If it is indeed a bug, then I suggest to report it at https://bugs.limesurvey.org/

Thanks!